# Can I generate a report of all the logged calls within the leads tab for a specific date range?

Tags: reporting, activities

I am only able to generate lead reports to view events and tasks. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create a report using the Activities with Leads [Report Type](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_report_type_guidelines.htm). There are some [special considerations with Activity Reports](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_activity.htm), but it should work very similarly to a normal report. All you need to do is set up the criteria you are looking to view and run the report after all of that.

Comment: As a side note, "logged calls" are tasks. It seems to confuse people.